# Can I run Windows Phone apps on Android devices?

Tags: emulators, windows-mobile

I need to run a Windows Phone 7 app developed for our company but no one has a Windows phone.

Is there any way I can run it on my Android, perhaps a simulator or something?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to run Windows Phone 7 apps on Android devices.

Comment: I believe you, but can you cite a source?  Of course, how do you cite a source for something that *doesn't* exist.

Comment: @Chahk - see my answer below! :)

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses Win32API binaries, along with an optional virtual machine called *.NET CLR* for .NET binaries, which encompasses C#, VB.NET, and Managed C++.

Whereas, Android apps, are written in Java that targets *DalvikVM*.

The nearest is *[MonoDroid](https://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)*, which enables apps written in .NET languages and sort of transliterates the compiled bytecode suitable for DalvikVM... I say transliterate.. it's not exactly 100% on the ball either and it's expensive as well! The added bonus with it, is cross-compilable for iOS too :)