# Run Windows Mobile 6 Classic Virtual Machine on Android

Tags: applications

I have a custom application that runs on Windows Mobile 6 Classic on a Psion Teklogix Workabout Pro G1/G2/G3. I am interested in running the same application without any alteration on an android device. Is there a way to run a virtual machine of Windows Mobile 6 Classic on an android device? Is there any other alternative to doing this without application alteration? 
Thanks.
Mudassar Choudhry

Comment: possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20530/can-i-run-windows-phone-apps-on-android-devices

Comment: Difference from question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20530/can-i-run-windows-phone-apps-on-android-devices is of the hardware (not of mobile phone) and OS version.